# HTTP POST Does not work with Route class in my ios application, swift 4.1

Tags: ios, routes, alamofire, swift4.1

I'm using Alamofire with swift 4.1, to work with http requests.I have writtent  seperate `Enum` for `Route` which it's type `URLRequestConvertible`. each and every time it gives me `404`. 
I use it like below.

```
 let urlRequest = Router.sendm(send).urlRequest

Alamofire.request(urlRequest!).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
                    print(response.response?.statusCode)
                    print(response)
                })
```

**Above code gives me 404 each time like below**

`Optional(404)
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}))`

> but I tried it in normal way like below

```
Alamofire.request("myurl", method: .post, parameters: ["keyone": "valone", "keytwo":"valtwo"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
            print(response)
            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }
    }
```

> 

**This is success**

What is the reason for this.

Comment: I believe your router is creating the URL the wrong way.Why don't you print your url before the alamofire call and check if it's ok?

Comment: nope, it is the correct one @GustavoConde